# Как правильно сделать override файла Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно отредактировать файл:

```
bitrix/modules/main/interface/auth/wrapper.php
```

Т.к. это ядро, то править его тут нельзя.

Подскажите, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Думаю, это невозможно. Могу описать как делать патчи, которые потом можно накатывать после обновления ядра.

Comment: @Сергей а какую цель преследуете модификацией файла ядра? Можно ведь написать свой модуль.

Comment: Нужно добавить только одну кнопку "Перейти на главную". Писать для этой цели свой модуль считаю неретабельным.